# Spacy lemmatizer suddenly returns other value than three months ago, words are not transformed into the singular form anymore

Tags: python, spacy, lemmatization

I used spacy a few months ago to lemmatize a large amount of text.
Today I had to rerun the written script and the output of spacy changed, it is mostly that plural forms of words are not transformed to the singular anymore.
I tried to reproduce the problem with a simpler use case and the word queen which breaks down to the following:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

sentence = "queen queenhat queens queen"

test = nlp(sentence)

for word in test:
    print(word.lemma_)
```

The output of this is: queen, queenhat, queens, queen

If I remove the last queen ("queen queenhat queens") the output is: queen, queenhat, queen

In that case, the s gets removed like it did three months ago.

I assumed from this that the s only gets removed if the queen is at the end, since the input "queen queenhat queens queens" also returns: queen queenhat queens queen

But if I at another queens the output becomes: queen queenhat queens queens queens in which case not even the last queen is transformed to the singular form anymore.

I assume this happens because I reinstalled spacy between today and three months ago and got a newer version, I fixed the problem by giving spacy only single words and no full texts, but this really slows the entire script  down from seconds to hours. This also happens for other words, queen is just the example I choose to test spacy with.

Is there someway I can fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: my guess is that library has been updated, you would have to roll it back to what it was 3 years ago, so you can go into documentation, see what version was back then remove and install back with pip your_ibrariry and version ==, see if that works out

Comment: Lemmatization depends on the part-of-speech tag that the model applies to your words so I would check if your model is different than before.  BTW... You should not expect to get proper lemitization if you're not giving the model an actual sentence.  This is because it may assign the wrong POS to a word and (for instance) think that "queens" is a verb and not remove the "s".  Try to give it a full sentence or manually assign the POS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the version of spaCy definitely changed, maybe from v2 to v3.

First, if spaCy is slow, see the [speed FAQ](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8402).

Next, note that spaCy's lemmatizer is clever, so it relies on the part of speech of a word, since that can affect the lemma. This is why changing the contents of your string changes your lemmas - spaCy thinks that's a weird sentence and tries to predict the part of speech of each word and probably doesn't do so well, since it's not actually a sentence. spaCy is designed to take natural language, like full sentences, as input, not arbitrary lists of words.

If you just need to lemmatize standalone words you're better off using the lemmatizer in spaCy as a standalone component or even using the underlying data files directly. There's not a guide for that but if you look at [spacy-lookups-data](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-lookups-data) you can access it easily enough.